# With ExpressionEngine, do you ever edit code with an editor or is it all within EE?

Tags: expressionengine

Just a quick question, I'm getting the idea that you don't. Why is this, and is there a way to? And why would you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I never code within the browser. The only reason to code in the EE CP would be if you're editing a snippet or global variable, and even then there are addons that will move those to flat files.

Take a look at this user guide on how to save templates as flat files: http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/templates_as_files.html Saving templates as files will also allow you to better version your template code with your VCS of choice.

When moving to a production environment you may want to consider syncing your template files to the database - as that may speed things up a tiny bit.

Comment: Cool. I figured there was a way, thanks!